# Moderators Pro Tem announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that every community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Ubiquitous]
[image: jmbejara]
[image: Jason Nichols]

**Update:**

We're now aways into this site's existence, and I'm very excited to welcome two new folks onto the pro-tem mod team! EconJohn and Kitsune Cavalry have both generously offered to step up and help care for the site. Please join me in welcoming them, and thanking jmbejara and Jason Nichols for their service in the community's crucial early days.

[image: Kitsune Cavalry]
[image: EconJohn]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them and appreciate the hard work and time they will contribute.

#### Did we overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members here who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. Our failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators should elected by the community, and that's why we'll hold elections once the site graduates.

Most of all, it's important to be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: That's a _really_ good team. Way to go!

Comment: Cheers to jmbejara and Jason Nichols! Thank you for your service! I look forward to working with my new colleagues. :)

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry Congrats to both of you! I hope you enjoy it!

Comment: This made my day. I won't let the forum down!

Comment: Initiative should be rewarded... and it was! I thank both our two new Pro Tem moderators for volunteering for moderator duty, and I wish them a successful and enjoyable ride!

Comment: Congrats @KitsuneCavalry and @EconJohn! You're going to be great!

Comment: Congrats @KitsuneCavalry and @EconJohn!